# Change Y label values to whole numbers

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I am making barcharts and accidentally changed a default setting. Previously, the code resulted in the y values as whole numbers (1), but now displays as float/integers (1.0).
I want to display whole numbers only.

```
data = rbind(c(1,2), c(2,1), c(3,0), c(4,3))
headers = c("bin", "rank")
colnames(data) = headers
View(data)

barplot(data$rank, main="First Control", horiz=FALSE, las =1 , ylab = "Use Rank",
        names.arg = data$bin)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `ylim=c(0,4)` to your code:

```
barplot(data$rank, ylim=c(0,4), main="First Control", horiz=FALSE, las =1 , ylab = "Use Rank",
        names.arg = data$bin)
```

Output:
[image]